# Use a different port for the app in docker

Tags: python, docker, networking, port

I have a Python app which creates containers for the project and the project database using Docker. By default, it uses port 80 and if we would like to create the multiple instances of the app, I can explicitly provide the port number,

```
# port 80 is already used, so, try another port
$ bin/butler.py setup --port=82
```

However, it also happens that the port info provided (using --port) is already used by another instance of the same app. So, it will be better to know which ports are already being used for the app and choose not to use any of them.

How do I know which ports the app use till now? I would like to execute that inside Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always use `subprocess` module, run `ps -elf | grep bin/butler.py` for example and parse the output with regex or simple string manipulation, then extract the used ports .

Comment: I get the error `ps: illegal option -- s
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-g grp[,grp...]] [-u [uid,uid...]]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
       ps [-L]`

Comment: my bad - it should be `ps -elf  | grep  bin/butler.py ` , will edit. 
are you using linux ?

Comment: the thing about `subprocess` module is that you can run whatever and exactly what you will write in the `cmd` so you just need to change the command `ps -elf ...` to `docker ps --format "{{.Ports}}"`

Answer (score 0):

[psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) might be the package you need. You can use the [`net_connections`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_connections) and grab listen ports from there.

```
[conn.laddr.port for conn in psutil.net_connections() if conn.status=='LISTEN']
```

```
[8000,80,22,1298]
```

Comment: is your answer return *all* `listen` connection or just the ones the python script use ?

Comment: This is listting all, you can change it simply to list only for curent pid

Comment: your answer does not answer the question very easily . you return all listening ports when the OP asked for specifically the ports used by his script.

Answer (score 0):

I write a solution where you can get all the ports used by docker from the Python code,

```
def cmd_ports_info(self, args=None):

    cmd = "docker ps --format '{{.Ports}}'"

    try:
        cp = subprocess.run(cmd,
                            shell=True,
                            check=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        cp = cp.stdout.decode("utf-8").strip()

        lines = str(cp).splitlines()
        ports = []

        for line in lines:

            items = line.split(",")

            for item in items:

                port = re.findall('\d+(?!.*->)', item)
                ports.extend(port)

        # create a unique list of ports utilized
        ports = list(set(ports))
        print(colored(f"List of ports utilized till now {ports}\n" + "Please, use another port to start the project", 'green',
                      attrs=['reverse', 'blink']))

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Docker exec failed command {e}")
        return None
```